# Space underneath list of images HTML/CSS

Tags: css

I am getting a blank space (which is currently a black line) underneath my list when an element is selected (all elements in list are images). I found a few threads suggesting vertical-align:middle and display:inline-block, but neither work or I am putting it in the wrong place here is my code and the JSFiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/6geo6qkv/

HTML

```
<div id="Gfilter">
    <ul id="grade" class="option-set sort">
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected"><img src="images/Filtre2.png" width="150"/></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-filter=".1"><img src="images/Filtre2.png" width="150"/></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#Gfilter {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.sort {
    width: 100%;
    font-size:55px;
}

.sort li {
    display:inline-block;
}

.sort ul {
    text-align:center;
}

.selected {
    background:black;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Provide JS fiddle please

Comment: Please fix your HTML… every `/img>` should be changed to `/>`. And remove `px` from the `width` attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your css

```
#grade a{
  display:block;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

<del>Also please fix your HTML, you have a `/img>` at the end of every img tag which is not necessary.</del>

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Will remove the /img thanks for the tip as well